# How to count a group by result with JPA and CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: jpa-2.0

I think this is nearly impossible or very tricky. I'm using CriteriaBuilder, JPA 2.0, Hibernate and MariaDB and want to build the following query with CriteriaBuilder:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT(SomeColumn) // I think this is not possible?
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ... COMPLEX CLAUSE ...
    GROUP BY SomeColumn) MyTable
```

My Question: Possible? And if, how?

Thanks for wrapping your mind around this!

Mark

Comment: With criteriabuilder, do you mean Criteria API? Criteria API supports both complex where statements, group by's, counts, distinct on single fields and subqueries. The biggest limitation i've seen is that you cannot perform custom joins.

Comment: Criteria API, yes. But it seems that there isn't a .from( Query ) or am I missing sth?

Comment: You use subqueries like cb.select(subquery). Anyways, I don't think a subquery is needed here, see my example below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example assumes that you're using Metamodel generation.

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Subquery<SomeColumnType> subcq = cq.subquery(SomeColumnType.class);
Root<MyTable> from = subcq.from(MyTable.class);
subcq.select(from.get(MyTable_.someColumn));
subcq.where(** complex where statements **);
subcq.groupBy(from.get(MyTable_.someColumn));
cq.select(cb.count(subcq));
```

Comment: No, in fact these two queries are not equivalent. My query count's the number of groups (single result), as your query will give a list of counts for each group (list of counts).

Comment: Ah that's true. Will have to think a bit on this one

Comment: Remove the group by, and count(distinct someColumn) will work as intended. Distinct does the grouping work for you.

Comment: Sorry, but it can't work that way. Count(distinct) and group by are "equivalent" in the inner query, but the count on the outside and on the inner query aren't.
Thanks for wrapping your head around this, but without a View or a NativeQuery this can't work (at least I think).

Comment: What data are you actually interested in? I thought it was the number of unique SomeColumn values?

Comment: No in the count of the numbers of unique SomeColumn values. I'm doing paging, and for the control I need the correct amount of values. The counts are displayed, but the pager needs the "count of counts" ^^

Comment: I can only assume relevant things are missing from your example query. because the query without subquery is truly equivalent to the one you specified. Back to the start: try my edited response.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, counting distinct group by elements, and stumbled across this Thread, based on the already existing answers I came up with the following

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Jpa1> countRoot = countQuery.from(Jpa1.class);

Subquery<Long> query = countQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Jpa1> root = query.from(Jpa1.class);

applyFilter(query, root);
query.groupBy(root.get("groupBy_column1"), root.get("groupBy_column2"));
query.select(builder.min(root.get("id_column")));

countQuery.where(builder.in(countRoot.get("id_column")).value(query));
return countQuery.select(builder.count(countRoot.get("id_column")));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have Spring Boot and you want to do the same, there is a better workaround that can only work for MySql 5/Maria by using the native `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS` (It won't work on MySQL 8);

The main idea of this integration is flexibility for Spring-Data and the ability to override the default `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` as follow

Step #1 - Create a custom `CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean`:

```
/**
* 
* @author ehakawati
*
* @param <R>
* @param <T>
* @param <I>
*/
public class CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    public CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends R> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        RepositoryFactorySupport repositoryFactorySupport = super.createRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
        repositoryFactorySupport.setRepositoryBaseClass(CustomJpaRepository.class);
        return repositoryFactorySupport;
    }

}
```

Step #2 - Create a custom `CustomJpaRepository`

```
 /**
 * 
 * @author ehakawati
 *
 * @param <T>
 * @param <ID>
 */
public class CustomJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
        implements Repository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager em;

    /**
     * 
     * @param entityInformation
     * @param entityManager
     */
    public CustomJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.em = entityManager;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param domainClass
     * @param entityManager
     */
    public CustomJpaRepository(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
        this.em = entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Reads the given {@link TypedQuery} into a {@link Page} applying the given
     * {@link Pageable} and {@link Specification}.
     *
     * @param query       must not be {@literal null}.
     * @param domainClass must not be {@literal null}.
     * @param spec        can be {@literal null}.
     * @param pageable    can be {@literal null}.
     * @return
     */
    protected <S extends T> Page<S> readPage(TypedQuery<S> query, final Class<S> domainClass, Pageable pageable,
            @Nullable Specification<S> spec) {

        if (pageable.isUnpaged()) {
            return super.readPage(query, domainClass, pageable, spec);
        }

        query.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
        query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.getResultList(), pageable, () -> getNativeCount());
    }

    /**
     * 
     */

    protected long getNativeCount() {

        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as `count`");

        return ((BigInteger) query.getSingleResult()).longValue();

    }

}
```

Step #3 - `PageableQueriesInterceptor`:

```
 /**
 * 
 * @author ehakawati
 *
 * @param <T>
 * @param <ID>
 */
public class PageableQueriesInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*?limit \\?(, \\?)?$");
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {

        if (PATTERN.matcher(sql).find()) {
            sql = sql.replaceFirst("select", "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ");
        }

        return sql;
    }
}
```

Step #4 - Enable `PageableQueriesInterceptor`:

```
sprint.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor= com.****.****.******.betterpaging.PageableQueriesInterceptor
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The CriteriaBuilder.countDistinct() method works nicely for counting groupBy results.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<MyEntity> root = cq.from(MyEntity);
        
cq.select(cb.countDistinct(root("entityField")));
cq.where(** your criteria **);

var result = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
var m = Math.toIntExact(result);
```

This would be like the SQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myEntity.entityField) FROM myEntity WHERE **blah** ;
```

And, of course, the countDistinct (like the COUNT(DISTINCT ...)) can have multiple columns listed as needed for grouping purposes.